# Speed up the Eliminate

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, algebraic-manipulation

I have problem of eliminating some variables from a set of equations, which contain logarithmic function, in order to obtain a differential equation.

These are the parameter and functions in `eq1`:

```
Ξ = (EE*((1 + B KK) Sqrt[M] Log[(1 - x0)/(1 - xw)] - 
B Δ Subscript[Θ, ∞])^2)/(\
Δ^2*(Γ*(1 - xw)*(Log[(1 - x0)/(1 - xw)] - 
Δ/Sqrt[M]*B*Subscript[Θ, ∞]) - 
KK*B*Subscript[Θ, ∞]));

g1 = ((Δ*Γ*(xi - xw) + KK*Sqrt[M]*
Log[(1 - x0)/(1 - xi)])*(Subscript[Θ, ∞] -\
Γ*(xi -xw)))/((Subscript[Θ, ∞] - \
Γ*(xi - xw))*Δ*B - 
Sqrt[M]*(1 + KK*B)*Log[(1 - x0)/(1 - xi)]);

g2 = ((Δ*Γ*(xi - xw) + 
KK*Sqrt[M]*Log[(1 - x0)/(1 - xi)])*(1 + KK*B))/(Δ*
B*(Subscript[Θ, ∞] - 
Γ*(xi - xw)) - (1 + KK*B)*Sqrt[M]*Log[(1 - x0)/(1 - xi)]);
```

These are the equations to be combined:

```
eq1 = H'[T] == 
1/Ξ*(EE*(Γ*(xi - xw) - B*g1))/(KK + g2);

eq2 = H[T] == (Δ*Γ*(xi - xw) + 
KK*Sqrt[M]*Log[(1 - x0)/(1 - xi)])/(Δ*
B*(Subscript[Θ, ∞] - 
Γ*(xi - xw)) - Sqrt[M]*(1 + KK*B)*Log[(1 - x0)/(1 - xi)]);

eq3 = Xp == (Log[(1 - x0)/(1 - xw)] (-Sqrt[M] (KK (1 + B KK) Sqrt[M] + 
(-1 + xw) Γ Δ) Log[(1 - x0)/(1 - xw)] + 
B (-1 + xw) Γ Δ^2 Subscript[\
Θ, ∞]))/((1 + B KK) Sqrt[M]*
Log[(1 - x0)/(1 - xw)] - 
B Δ Subscript[Θ, ∞])^2;

Eliminate[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, {EE, Δ, Γ, M, 
KK, B, Subscript[Θ, ∞], xi, xw, x0}]
```

The long running time implies that there should be some tricks to deal with suck
kind of problem. I think the issue is lying in the logarithmic function. [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28773/speed-up-eliminate) is a very similar answered question.

Comment: Solving one by one might help. Solve the first equation for any parameter (say \xi), substitute that parameter in equation system, then `Simplify`, and try again. This is helping Mathematica to eliminate. Since Mathematica tries to solve this equation system at once, it might be slow.

Comment: Why have you asked again? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101004/5478

Comment: Hi, @Kuba, I am so sorry. I feel the previous post is too long. I just want to change it into a more concise form. Do you suggest me to delete it :) Could you pls give me some hints to the problem? Many thanks!

Comment: @gurluk, Let me have a try and then give a feedback!

Comment: Hi,@gurluk, I follow your advice to do these things: First not assign `\[CapitalXi]`, `Solve[eq1, xi] // FullSimplify` to obtain `xi`, then plug it in `eq2`, `(eq2 /. xi ->1 + E^((\[CapitalDelta] \[CapitalXi] Derivative[1][H][T])/(EE Sqrt[M])) (-1 + x0)) // FullSimplify`, and assign the resulting `H[T]` as `eq4 = H[T]` (note the expression has **not** be pasted here), the process is fine up to now, then I try `Eliminate[{eq3, eq4}, x0]`, however, it is slow again...help